# Getting CTRL characters with NCurses

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, curses

How are control keys obtained from the NCurses library? I need to know if a result from `getch ()` is a character pressed with *ctrl*, and what character was pressed with it. I googled "ctrl keys ncurses" and "control keys ncurses" without much results.

I know from a quick test that (at least in my case) all the CTRL characters are related to the characters by a difference of 96.

ie

```
akey is 97
^Akey is 1
bkey is 98
^Bkey is 2
ckey is 99
^Ckey is 3
```

But this doesn't seem like reliable information to write a program with. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That actually is reliable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards) (but with 64, not 96). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> all the way through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd> are handled properly (use of Ctrl-@ is discouraged due to other meanings of NUL).

Comment: I see, the difference between lower and upper case is 32, which is why I saw 96 instead of 64. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the straight ASCII-tests, with *ncurses* you can use the [`unctrl`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-unctrl) or [`keyname`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-keyname_key_name) functions to return a string which has the relevant information parsed:

- if the length of the returned string is one, it is a simple character
- if the length is two, and the first character is **`^`**, then it is a control character and the corresponding canonical pressed-with character is the second character of the string.

  Keep in mind that there may be several possibilities for *pressed-with*, since <kbd>*Shift*</kbd> is ignored, and there are a few special cases such as <kbd>*Control*</kbd><kbd>*Space*</kbd> versus <kbd>*Control*</kbd>**`@`** which can produce the same result.

That's with *ncurses*: other implementations of `unctrl` may return a null pointer for character codes 128-255.  [X/Open Curses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-unctrl_wunctrl) is vague on what should be done in that case.